# Switching between forms in Subform panel in Microsoft access

Tags: forms, ms-access-2007

I am new in Microsoft Access. What i want is to switch between forms in subform panel depending upon the user selects from drop down list. Attach file contains what i want [image]

I google alot but didnt find any help. Thank you for your help.

Here is screen shot. but I am confused in finding control of subform.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Forms("frmMain").Form.subFormControl.SourceObject = "SubForm_2_A"
```

..should be all you need.
`subFormControl` is the *name* of the subform-container-control that contains Subform2.
`frmMain` is the name of the parent form, not labelled in your picture (actually, you might not have to put subform1 in a subform really, its content could be on the parent form).

EDIT:
The red frame marks a subform. Click on -1- to make sure the main form has the focus. Then click *once* on -2- and the control is selected, and its properties show up in the properties box on the right.
Note that you find the "source object" in the data page and the name of the control in the "other" page. Access makes the name (of the control) the same as the form, which is really not such a bright idea and rather confusing.

[image: SampleImage]

Comment: where I can find this subFormControl ??

Comment: When you open the main form (that holds the other subforms), click once on the subform, then the control should be selected. If you click on it again, the focus goes inside that subform, which can be a bit confusing. When the subform-control is selected, you can find its name in the properties box.